# converting JS array with objects to HTML collection

Tags: javascript

I got to the point with my project where I decided to simplify some of the js functions where I am looking for a parent in a DOM tree, then drill down to the elements many many times in one function. instead I though I will make instances of a function which will keep some data so then I can refer and operate on objects in easy way. I got it working but as I was going along, I decided to extend functionality and add some extra functions like `getElementsByClassNameThenTagName`.
I loop through the arrays and if add matching elements to the array.
I have noticed (sadly only now) that I am creating an array with elements rather than HTML collection. As a results, I cannot refer to the objects in my findings by typing `buttons['reset'].disabled = false;`. I can access my reset button by `buttons[3].disabled = false;` but this would cause a lot of inconvenience.

I am therefore looking for a way to convert my array with object into a HTML collection.

Please see below my current function:

```
this.getElementsByClassNameThenTagName = function (elementClass, elementTag) {
    if (parentNode == null) {
        this.init();
    }
    var results = [];
    var regexStr = elementClass;
    var regex = new RegExp(regexStr);
    var x = moduleNode.getElementsByClassName(elementClass);
    // console.log(x);
    var y;
    for ( var i = 0; i < x.length; i++ ) {
        // console.log(i);
        y = x[i].getElementsByTagName(elementTag);
        // console.log(y);
        for (var k=0; k<y.length; k++){
            // console.log(y[k]);
            results.push(y[k]);
        }
        // console.log(results);
    }
    return results;
};
```

Any suggestions please?

Thanks.

Comment: you have to post the code for `getElementsByClassNameThenTagName`  there has to be a point in there where you have an HTML collection and you are turning it into a conventional array , fix that instead of converting it back

Comment: sorry with code now.

Comment: I didn't notice that a nodelist is readonly, you might just have to actually rethink your design a little bit.  There isn't going to be any solution that is exactly what you're looking for

Comment: I know it doesn't really answer the question, but for this particular case you could just use `document.querySelectorAll('.classname tagname')`.

Comment: you could look into how jquery does it when you type `#('.classname > tagname')`

Comment: @ScottSelby but jQuery doesn't return HTML Collections, just a jQuery object.

Comment: like I said , there is no actual answer for this that is exactly what OP wants

Comment: You said `buttons['reset'].disabled = false;` what is `'reset'`? An ID?

Comment: reset is actually a name of the button. Before having a HTML collection i could refer to the button named reset just by typing `buttons['reset']`. Now having an array, this way is no longer available.

Comment: Are names unique throughout the DOM? Or at least in all the matched elements?

Comment: they are unique only in a matched elements hence I thought that by doing "project specific functions" will simplify my issue.

Comment: @azgooon BTW if you want to get to specific button by name you could also use `document.forms[formname][buttonname]` so you can avoid traversing the whole DOM just to get to it https://jsfiddle.net/ddqsy8f3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.getElementsByClassNameThenTagName = function (elementClass, elementTag) {
    if (parentNode == null) {
        this.init();
    }

    var results = {};  // thid should be an object (collection)
    var x = moduleNode.querySelectorAll("." + elementClass + " " + elementTag);
    x.forEach(function(y) {
        var name = y.getAttribute("name"); // if you really sure that all the matched elements have names
        results[name] = y;
    });
    return results;
};
```

Now you can use the `results` array like this:

```
var someElement = results['some name'];
```

**NOTE:** All the matched elements `x` should have a `name` attribute, and all the `name` attributes of the matched elements should be unique.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you Ibrahim, I really appreciate it. 
By all means, Scott and Pawel, thank you as well for your input.